# How to make the inherited class run a method from same class in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance

Whats wrong with me OOP here.

I want to inherit from `Class A`

The `return_output` method will do something common so I don't want to write that in the inherited classes.

However when I do `B->return_output()` I want it to run the `do_something` method in `Class B`, but I see that it always runs the method from `Class A`.

Should I replace `$this` with something else?

```
class A {
    private function do_something() {
        // do something
    }

    public function return_output() {
        $op = $this->do_something();

        // add some wrappers to $op
        return $op;
    }
}


class B extends A {    
    private function do_something() {
        // do something different
    }    
}


var newClass = new B;
echo B->return_output();
```

Comment: `var newClass = new B; echo B->return_output();` looks like JS, not PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use protected and not private since you are running it inside of scope a and scope b can't access private scope a:

```
class A {
        protected function do_something() {
            echo('ado_something');
        }

        public function return_output() {
            $op = $this->do_something();

            // add some wrappers to $op
            return $op;
        }
    }


    class B extends A {    
        protected function do_something() {
             echo('bdo_something');
        }    
    }


    $newClass = new B;
    echo $newClass->return_output();
```

Comment: This calls `A::do_something` from `A::return_output`. See for my answer when you want to call `B::do_something`.

Comment: this is `B::do_something` - the output in this case will be: `bdo_something` - like i have explain - since the original call is from instance B it access it's protected function and not the parent

Comment: One question: If I now want to call A::do_something, do I have to use `self::do_something`?

Comment: Yes - but it's kind of un-logical to do it that way - if you want to call parent class from B you can use `parent::do_something();` and from your self you can use `self::do_something()` like you've said but in that case you'll better call it from instance A and not from instance B

Comment: `$this` always "keeps" its context